# Is unique_lock unlocked when a function is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Let's say I have a situation like this:

```
void consumer(){
   unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
   foo();  
}

void foo(){
    /* does the thread still own the mutex here? */
}
```

I expect it does but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The mutex will be unlocked as soon `lock` leaves scope.

Comment: why would it? maybe make a small modification to your example, by passing a reference to the lock to `foo` (just for the sake of the example) and then ask yourself the same question again

Comment: You need to be more precise in what you're asking. You probably mean when the function exits, not when it's called.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Tt's not the scope that matters, it's the _extent_. The scope of a variable is the set of program statements that potentially could access the variable. The body of function `foo()` is outside of the scope of the `lock` variable because `lock` is local to the `consumer` function. But, the _extent_ of a variable is the span of time during which its value continues to exist. I.e., the span of time between when the value was constructed, and when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The destructor of `unique_lock` calls `mtx.unlock()`. The destructor is called at the end of the lifetime of the lock. Generally (see comments), the end of the lifetime of the lock is :

```
void consumer(){
   unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
   foo();  
} // <- here.
```

So yes, it'll still be locked.

Comment: It's technically wherever you leave the function. If might be at `foo()` if it throws. Edit : Though I suppose it doesn't matter. You can safely assume it's at the end of the block and if ever the function leaves elsewhere then you're safe in your assumption because anything after that point won't be reached.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point, the general case would apply then in this case.